# Setting text on label by javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me with this.
I have a function on my page to be called by the AjaxAsyncFileupload control.

```
 function uploadComplete1(sender, args) { 
   var file1 = new String(args.filename).toLowerCase(); 
   if (file1.indexOf('docx', file1.length - 4) == -1 && file1.indexOf('doc', file1.length - 3) == -1 && file1.indexOf('xlsx', file1.length - 4) == -1 && file1.indexOf('xls', file1.length - 3) == -1) {
      var elem = document.getElementById("ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblUploadedFile1Minor_Network_Change");
   elem.InnerHTML = 'This file is not allowed.'; elem.style.visibility = "visible"; 
      } 
   }
```

When this function is called, I get an error: "Unhandled exception: Cannot set property InnerHTML of null"

I cann't find out why I get this error. The label it needs to set the text of, is on the page. I even took the exact name via chrome-pageinspect to make sure I have the right name.

This script is put in the page via code behind after the label has been added to the controls of the page.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's `innerHTML`, not `InnerHTML` - JavaScript is case sensitive.  Also, it's generally frowned upon to use the `new String()` construct, except for specific niche cases.

Comment: Are you sure the id "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblUploadedFile1Minor_Network_Change" already exists when this function is called ? In other words, isn't that id invalid, or isn't the code called before document is ready event ?

Comment: When I inspect the element in Chrome, I see the label present on the page. So it does exist.

Comment: Changing from InnerHTML to innerHTML does not change anything. Still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

check your "elem" is not null when you set innerHTML

Comment: How can I check this? The element is on the page, exactly by the ID. Does it matter if it is inside a div?

Comment: @Eric: add an `alert()` or `console.log()` to the function to show what `elem` is inside the function.

Comment: f it is null, it's probably because the document is not fully loaded, in which case you could use $(document).ready() or window.onload